# Загрузка останавливается на "random: crng init done"

Tags: linux, centos

Потерял доступ к виртуальной машине на сервере centos 7. Пробую разные методы сброса через vnc консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы не пробовал, происходит следующее: загрузка зависает на random crng init done

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что если подождать минут пятнадцать?

Comment: Энтер не пробовали нажать на всякий случай?

Comment: Нажимайте на клавиши, пробуйте увеличить энтропию. Оба предыдущих комментария в правильном направлении.

Comment: А вот если не сработает `init=/bin/sh` Вам а помощь!

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev попробую, спасибо

Comment: @andreymal да пробывал, не помогает(

Comment: rw init=/bin/sh так прописать??